# AngularJS - Controller not working inside a diretive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controller

Im trying to get some variables or call some methods from a controller of a directive but it is not working.

I have imported all needed files injected everything needed.
If I use the same approach but I use `templateUrl` it is working but this is not, what am I doing wrong ?

Here is just some part of my code.

```
class Application {

    constructor($router, alertsHandlerService) {
        this.$router = $router;
        this.routing();
        this.alertsHandlerService = alertsHandlerService;
        console.log("app construct");

    }



    routing(){
        this.$router.config(
            {
                path: '/',
                component: {'main': 'main'} // view-name:component => name.html, NameController
            }
        );
    }

    skuska(){
        console.log("skuska called");
    }
}

Application.$inject = ['$router', 'alertsHandlerService'];

export default function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: Application,
        controllerAs: 'applicationCtrl'
    };
};
```

And my shortened html file

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="agenda" application class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<body>
{{ applicationCtrl.skuska() }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the `Application` controller in your `agenda` module.

```
import Application from './path/to/controller/Application.js';
import applicationDirective from './path/to/directive/application.js';

Application.$inject = ['$router', 'alertsHandlerService'];

angular
    .module('agenda', []) // app dependencies
    .controller('ApplicationCtrl', Application)
    .directive('application', applicationDirective);
```

and then you just do

```
function applicationDirective () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ApplicationCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
}

export default applicationDirective;
```

and

```
class Application {

    constructor($router, alertsHandlerService) {
        this.$router = $router;
        this.routing();
        this.alertsHandlerService = alertsHandlerService;
        console.log("app construct");
    }

    routing(){
        this.$router.config(
            {
                path: '/',
                component: {'main': 'main'} // view-name:component => name.html, NameController
            }
        );
    }

    skuska(){
        console.log("skuska called");
    }
}

export default Application;
```

Something like this should work properly (not tested).

Comment: @marnitas I have something like you wrote except I register Application in another module, which is then injected to agenda module as dependency

Comment: So i think you are breaking the rule of single responsibility. Controllers should be dedicated to specific view or directive. If you want to make your controllers more reusable I think you should consider inheritance. But still - modules should be single responsible.